# What do the filters do in this function? How are we returning what we return?

Tags: javascript

How does the code below work?

```
function areSimilar(a, b) {
const ad = a.filter((v,i)=>v!=b[i])
const bd = b.filter((v,i)=>v!=a[i])
return ad.length == 0 || (ad.length == 2 && ad.join('') == 
bd.reverse().join(''))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not already aware, filter is a higher order array function which takes a predicate function as a parameter, runs that function on every element of the array, and returns a new array containing only the elements for which the predicate returned true. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter.

In the case of `a.filter((v, i) => v != b[i])`, each `a[i]` of `a` is being tested to see if it is equal to `b[i]`. If it is equal, then it is filtered out. The resulting array `ad` will contain only elements of `a` that are different between the arrays. The same with `bd`.

If `ad` has length 0, then there are no differences between a and b, so the function returns true. The next part depends on the definition of 'similar' - It seems the author's intent was to mark two arrays as similar if they are either identical, or if they have all the same elements, but with one and only one pair of elements swapped.

If one pair of elements is swapped, then there will be exactly two elements in both ad, and bd - But their contents will be switched around, so the author reverses bd, then checks if it's the same as ad.

Example:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let b = [1, 4, 3, 2]
```

Then, `ad == [2, 4]` and `bd == [4,2]` so `ad.join('') == bd.reverse().join('')`

Note: The join is so that the arrays can be compared as values, so the final comparison would be `"24" === "24"`

Comment: Thank for this great answer. And yes that's what the author was trying to do, to see if two arrays are equal or if there's max one pair of numbers we could swap out of one array and exchange with the other to make the array equal. 

That would make sense with the reverse method and join, the reversal of the second array is equal to the first, as long as ad.length==2. If we had three same elements that we could swap out of each array to make the arrays the "same", this would return false, and we wouldn't say the arrays are "similar" then.

does ad.length == 3 ? Nope, so return false